# JMeter, how to loop once for every sampler in an Interleave controller

Tags: loops, jmeter

I'm using JMeter to automate some tests, and I have a pretty basic set up with a login and logoff piece and then a number of individual tests. What I want is for each test to log in, do its thing, and log out. Right now, all tests are in an interleave controller, with the login/out pieces being outside. If I have 10 tests I set the ThreadGroup to loop 10 times, and everything works as I expect.

However, we have 3 people writing their own individual tests that should go into the interleave controller, and the number of tests is growing. It's becoming a little troublesome to make sure that the number of ThreadGroup loops matches the number of tests by counting manually, and I'm looking for a way to tell JMeter to loop as many times as there are children in the Interleave controller. Any suggestions?

I wouldn't mind trying out a different structure as well, as long as it does what I want and doesn't force people to add the login/out pieces to every single test.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: See also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26843012/loop-interleave-controller

Answer (score 1):

What about:

- Isolating login / logout in their single Test Plan using Test Fragment
- Each user would have his own Test Plan and use the previous one through an IncludeController
- he would use ModuleController to call them in his tests

I am not sure this is the right answer, but to make it a better one please explain what you are trying to achieve accross the 3 people team

Comment: The problem isn't that we have 3 people and need to somehow share tests. The question is: how can I loop through x-number of tests, with every test running a test fragment before and after itself, given that x is large and changes often.

Answer (score 0):

Although an old question ;-) 
I would likely solve it like this, if I had to:

- Loop controller [forever]

  - Login

    - Interleave

      - Once Only Controller

        - test 1
      - Once Only Controller

        - test 2
      - Once Only Controller

        - test x
      - Once Only Controller

        - Logout
        - Test Action [Stop]
- Logout

Set the thread group to one thread, to run once. And you would be good to go. The last test would be empty (e.g. it logged in and logged out again). If that would be an issue, you could think of adding the test action to any last test executed.

From my perspective I wouldn't solve it like this. Just run the different sets created by the different team members. Working on one jmx is a pain in the bud anyway...

note: I would be interested to know how you *did* solve it ;-)