# Loop interleave controller

Tags: jmeter

I am trying to use the interleave controller inside another controller (ForEach OR Loop OR any other) such that each of the sampler (which is HTTP request) under Interleave controller is executed once and the test exits the "outer" controller once the last sampler is done.

My test plan looks somewhat like show below

```
test plan
--Loop controller ( with loop count = num of requests in Interleave Controller)
----Some test elements
----Interleave Controller
--------HTTP requests (count = n, with some differences)
----Some More test elements
```

The test plan is to test multiple test scenarios of a lot of REST services (having some changes in the request data etc) so some services might have 2 scenarios some might have 10.

Thus is there any way of getting the number of samplers under the interleave controller ? OR a better design to my test plan.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [interleave](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Interleave_Controller) documentation as it explains nicely how it works and how one sampler, going from top to bottom, is executed *per iteration*. If you want only one sampler executed randomly (*per iteration*) you can use the [random controller](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Random_Controller).

Note: Those controllers don't stop by them selves if all children have been executed. They start all over again. If you want to stop you have to add different logic to make that happen.